# Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function setUrl() on null in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image-upload

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setUrl() on null in
>   /app/code/local/Ced/CsProduct/Block/Media/Uploader.php on line 37

I'm using the below code

```
$this->getConfig()->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/upload'));
```

Comment: at the end why it's double slash `getUrl('//upload'));` ? is it on purpose?

Comment: getUrl('*/*/upload')); code is this..

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to achieve by this code?

Comment: Actually case is that i have create the new product choose product type then continue then showing that error..

Comment: Try this code `Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("*/*/upload")`.

Comment: sorry problem not solved.

Comment: $this->getConfig()->setUrl(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/upload'));

Comment: Any Body can HELP??????

Answer (score 1):

Change;

```
$this->getConfig()->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/upload'));
```

To;

```
    $this->getUploader()->getUploaderConfig->setUrl(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/upload'));
```